# Check Password Strength using Wordpress API

Tags: rest-api, password

I am looking to check the strength of a password using the WordPress API.  I cant seem to find a function that allows me to do so. The code be

```
<?php
    add_action( 'custom_api_init', function () {
        // Check Password Strength
        register_rest_route( 
            'custom/v2', 
            '/strength/', 
            array( 
                'methods' => 'POST', 
                'callback' => 'custom_api_strength'
            ) 
        );
    }

    function custom_api_strength($data){
        if(
            isset(
                $data['password'],
                $data['username'],
                $data['email'],
                $data['fname'],
                $data['lname']
            )
        ){

            // Check Password Strength


            return array('result'=>$strength);
        }else{ return array( 'result'=>'0'); }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

WordPress uses the [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) javascript library by Dropbox, to estimate the password strength.

We can see the implementation in:

- [/wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter.js](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6fd8080e7ee7599b36d4528f72a8ced612130b8c/wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter.js)
- [/wp-admin/js/user-profile.js](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6fd8080e7ee7599b36d4528f72a8ced612130b8c/wp-admin/js/user-profile.js)

with:

```
strength = wp.passwordStrength.meter( 
    pass1, 
    wp.passwordStrength.userInputBlacklist(),
    pass1 
);
```

As far as I know there's no explicit PHP WordPress API for estimating the password strength, but *zxcvbn* has been ported to a PHP library [here](https://github.com/bjeavons/zxcvbn-php) (I'm not related to it) and here are usage examples from the docs:

```
use ZxcvbnPhp\Zxcvbn;

$userData = [
  'Marco',
  'marco@example.com'
];

$zxcvbn = new Zxcvbn();
$weak = $zxcvbn->passwordStrength('password', $userData);
echo $weak['score']; // will print 0

$strong = $zxcvbn->passwordStrength('correct horse battery staple');
echo $strong['score']; // will print 4
```

Comment: ps: here I played with a [patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37604#comment:5) to add the password strength info to the email sent to admin when a user changes the password.